# Application Requires Cross Domain Authentication - No trust

Tags: active-directory, trust-relationship, ad-lds, cross-domain

I've an application that going forward is going to require cross domain authentication using an AD service account across 2 separate organisations - for example domain A application needs to authenticate with domain B backend.

Does anyone know of a way that I could get cross domain authentication working without a domain trust in place between 2 separate organisations - due to security concerns this isn't desirable?

Could AD LDS work in anyway - I believe an AD Trust would still be required?
Any other ideas greatly appreciated?

Thanks in advance,
PJ

Comment: Sure there is. No-one is going to create trusts between two separate companies. Most use federation in this scenario. (ADFS or another solution like Ping).

Comment: Thanks Greg, but would this work for internal apps that are using AD service accounts, no user interaction (not external facing at all) between the 2 organisations? Thanks JP.